# octave plot() not recognizing fmt string

Tags: octave

According to the [documentation for plot()](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Two_002dDimensional-Plots.html), I should be able to pass a format argument to control the style of the graph.  However, Octave seems to be misinterpreting this as an incomplete property specification, rather than a format string:

```
$ octave-cli
GNU Octave, version 4.4.1
Copyright (C) 2018 John W. Eaton and others.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".

Additional information about Octave is available at https://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit https://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read https://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

1> t = linspace(0,5,1001);
2> plot(t, sin(pi*t), "g_;sin(πt)");
error: plot: properties must appear followed by a value
error: called from
    __plt__ at line 90 column 15
    plot at line 223 column 10
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: that's clearly not a valid formatting specification. what are you trying to do with that `sin(πt)` in there?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou It is a "displayname" which is the label to use for the plot legend.  Why do you say it's invalid?  Also, even if you just use "g_" for a green solid line, it gives the same error.

Comment: ok I was not aware of this particular legend syntax since I tend to set it separately, but, in any case, follow the specification exactly and you'll find the typo. Specifically, it's a dash not an underscore, and if you use the label it seems you need to use a semicolon both before AND after the labelname, i.e. `plot(t, sin(pi*t), "g-;sin(πt);");`

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou thanks for the eagle eye!  somehow, i missed those things.  if you want to make your comment into an official answer, i'll accept it. otherwise, i'll self-accept so it doesn't look still unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer as requested

From the documentation:

> The fmt format argument can also be used to control the plot style. It is a string composed of four optional parts: "<linestyle><marker><color><;displayname;>"

where, valid linestyles are:

> ‘-’      Use solid lines (default).
>     ‘--’     Use dashed lines.
>     ‘:’      Use dotted lines.
>     ‘-.’     Use dash-dotted lines.

Based on the above, you have two typos in the format string.

The first is that you used an 'underscore' (`_`) instead of a 'dash' (`-`) as your linestyle specifier.

The second is that you didn't 'enclose' the "displayname" in semicolons as the syntax expects; you only put the left semicolon but forgot the right one.

So the correct format string would be:

```
plot( t, sin( pi * t ), "g- ;sin(πt);" );
```